Should the total population include number of units in stratum where the number of units sampled in the stratum is $\leq$ 1?
A survey of 100 houses across 20 states in a country is conducted with each state being used as a stratum. To find the population mean I know i need to use the formula
$$\bar{y}_{str}=\Sigma^{20}_{h=1} \frac{N_h}{N}\bar{y}_h$$
where h denotes each stratum, $N_h$ denotes the stratum size, N denotes the total population size and $\bar{y}_h$ denotes the sample mean.
However in two of the stratum 0 houses where sampled, which means they do not have a sample mean. Do i include the population of the stratums in the total population when calculating the $\bar{y}_{str}$?
Additionally i need to calculate the 95% CI for this result. I know this includes finding the sample variance for each stratum and using the following formula:
$$\Bbb{V}(\bar{y}_{str})=\Sigma_{h=1}^{20}\frac{N_h}{N}^2(1-\frac{n_h}{N_h})\frac{s_h^2}{n_h}$$
However 3 of the stratum only have one observation and so a sample variance cannot be calculated. So should i include the population sizes of these stratum in the total population when calculating $\Bbb{V}(\bar{y}_{str})$.
Also the CI requires both $\bar{y}_{str}$ and $\Bbb{V}(\bar{y}_{str})$, so surely the N value used in these would have to be the same? So would N be the total population of all stratum, including the ones with $\leq$ 1 sampled units or would i not include these?
